# How can I change the position of the side bar to right?

Tags: css, reactjs

https://codepen.io/darkz/pen/BGawva

I am working on creating a sidebar in React.
I used `right: 0` style for the `.menu`, but it still appears on the left side.
What am I missing?

Comment: position:absolute;

Comment: There is small typo at .menu { position: absolute }, but you are on good track...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `menu` css fix typo

```
position: absolute;
```

and add

```
right: 0;
```

So in the end it should look like this

```
.menu {
  background: #34495e;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
  opacity:0; 
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  right: 0;
```

It should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:0` to push things on right. And remember to remove `right:0`.